# why its contradicts the minimality of $g(x)$ unless $r(x) = 0 ?$

Tags: field-theory

Taken from Dummit /Foote book page no : $520$

I have some doubt in given below proof , my doubt marked in red line
[image]

My doubt is that  why its   contradicts the minimality of $g(x)$ unless $r(x) = 0 ?$

My thinking : Here we have already taken $r( \alpha)= 0$ implies $r(x)=0$

Then why it written  unless $r(x)=0$ ?

Comment: The point is precisely why  $r(\alpha)=0\implies r(x)=0$.

Comment: because both $r(\alpha)$ and $r(x)$  are  same  @Bernard

Comment: Not at all. $r(\alpha)$ is the evaluation of $r(x)$ at $\alpha$ (an element of a field extension of $F$), whereas $x$ is an indeterminate and $r(x)$ a polynomial with coefficients in $F$.

Comment: The point is to *prove* $r(x)=0$, so that you can conclude the polynomial $g(x)$ divides the polynomial $f(x)$. So are you asking why $r(\alpha)=0$ implies $r(x)$ is the zero polynomial?

Comment: @halrankard my confusion : it contradicts the minimality of $g(x)$ unless $r(x) = 0$ mean if $r(x) =0 $ then it will not contradicts  the minimality of $g(x)$ .  same thing why not  valid for $r(\alpha)=0$

Comment: yes @halrankard

Comment: @Bernard then it should be like its contradicts the minimality of $g(\alpha)?$ not  $g(x)$

Comment: No, if you suppose $r(x)\ne 0$ and $r(\alpha)=0$, it  contradicts the minimality of $\deg g(x)$.

Comment: okss thanks u now got its @Bernard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(x)$ is chosen to be a nonzero$^\ast$ polynomial of minimal degree that has $\alpha$ has a root. Then later in the proof, there is a polynomial $r(x)$ that has $\alpha$ as a root and has degree smaller than $g(x)$. So the only possible way this can happen is that $r(x)$ is the zero polynomial.

So it's not just that "$r(\alpha)=0$ implies $r(x)=0$"; rather it's that "$r(\alpha)=0$ and $\deg(r(x))<\deg(g(x))$ implies $r(x)=0$."

---

$^*$ The word "nonzero" is not present in the proof when $g(x)$ is chosen. But this is implied by the context.

Comment: An excellent clarification. Plus one.